# General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value ( QUERY EXEPTION )

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm trying to add some data in the database from a form but I got an exeption :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"ID_ARTICLE":58}]' for column 'ID_ARTICLE' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `annonce` (`TITRE_ANNONCE`, `TYPE_ANNONCE`, `PRIX`, `ID_ARTICLE`) values (titre, 1, 100, [{"ID_ARTICLE":58}]))
```

which mean I can't insert the ID_ARTICLE which is an integer 
here is my query :

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $annonce = new annonce;

```
    $IDARTICLE = DB::table('article')
        ->select('ID_ARTICLE')
        ->where('NOM_ARTICLE', $request->NOM_ARTICLE)
        ->get();


    $annonce->TITRE_ANNONCE = $request->TITRE_ANNONCE;
    $annonce->TYPE_ANNONCE = $request->TYPE_ANNONCE;
    $annonce->PRIX = $request->PRIX;
    $annonce->ID_ARTICLE = $IDARTICLE;
    $annonce->save();

    return ($annonce);
}
```

I tried to replace

```
$annonce->ID_ARTICLE = $IDARTICLE;
```

with

```
  $annonce->ID_ARTICLE = $IDARTICLE->ID_ARTICLE;
```

to retrieve the integer value from the list but shows another error : Property [ID_ARTICLE] does not exist on this collection instance.

when it exists as we can see 
any help would be appreciable thanks

Comment: Change ->get() to  ->first() because  $IDARTICLE is returning multiple of results. You need one.

Comment: i did but it shows another error  : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `$IDARTICLE` contains multiple results set. You have to fetch id of specific records and insert into another table like this.

```
 $IDARTICLE = DB::table('article')
        ->select('ID_ARTICLE')
        ->where('NOM_ARTICLE', $request->NOM_ARTICLE)
        ->first();


    $annonce->TITRE_ANNONCE = $request->TITRE_ANNONCE;
    $annonce->TYPE_ANNONCE = $request->TYPE_ANNONCE;
    $annonce->PRIX = $request->PRIX;
    $annonce->ID_ARTICLE = $IDARTICLE->ID_ARTICLE;
$annonce->save();

return ($annonce);
```

Comment: its not working : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: have you change method `get()` to `first()` ?

Comment: Hey, it works i replaced get() with the method first() then  $IDARTICLE with $IDARTICLE->ID_ARTICLE;

Comment: The answer has been modified. Just replace `$IDARTICLE->id` with `$IDARTICLE->ID_ARTICLE`;